# Unexpected logout in Symfony 2.5 after interactive login

Tags: session, symfony, authentication, upgrade, logout

After upgrade from 2.4.6 to 2.5 users get logged out every hour or two, though ttl is not that small. Switching back fixes the problem.

```
framework:
    session:
        name:            SESSID
        handler_id:      session.handler.pdo
        cookie_lifetime: 259200
```

Login is done with ajax.

```
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword()/* null */,
                                        'main', $user->getRoles());
    $this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
    $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($this->getRequest(), $token);
    $this->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch(SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN, $event);
```

Does anyone know about changes to symfony which could cause this? Or better and still simple way to log in?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem and I solved it by setting a value to gc_maxlifetime in config.yml. For that, I had a look to  PdoSessionHandler.php and in the read method:

```
public function read($sessionId)
{
    $this->beginTransaction();

    try {
        $this->lockSession($sessionId);

        // We need to make sure we do not return session data that is already considered garbage according
        // to the session.gc_maxlifetime setting because gc() is called after read() and only sometimes.
        $maxlifetime = (int) ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime');

        $sql = "SELECT $this->dataCol FROM $this->table WHERE $this->idCol = :id AND $this->timeCol > :time";

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $sessionId, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':time', time() - $maxlifetime, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        // We use fetchAll instead of fetchColumn to make sure the DB cursor gets closed
        $sessionRows = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_NUM);

        if ($sessionRows) {
            return base64_decode($sessionRows[0][0]);
        }

        return '';
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        $this->rollback();

        throw $e;
    }
}
```

I looked especially these two lines:

1. `$maxlifetime = (int) ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime');`
   and
2. `$stmt->bindValue(':time', time() - $maxlifetime, \PDO::PARAM_INT);`

So, I have defined in config.yml:

```
session:
    handler_id:  session.handler.pdo
    cookie_lifetime: 259200
    gc_maxlifetime: 259200
```

I think that default php.ini value is taken for gc_maxlifetime if it is not defined (here $maxlifetime). So when user is inactive more than gc_maxlifetime, he is disconnected. cookie_lifetime will force user to be disconected after cookie_lifetime seconds.

PS: In Symfony 2.4 there was this code where gc_maxlifetime was not used:

```
public function read($sessionId)
{
    $sql = "SELECT $this->dataCol FROM $this->table WHERE $this->idCol = :id";

    try {
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $sessionId, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        // We use fetchAll instead of fetchColumn to make sure the DB cursor gets closed
        $sessionRows = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_NUM);

        if ($sessionRows) {
            return base64_decode($sessionRows[0][0]);
        }

        return '';
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('PDOException was thrown when trying to read the session data: %s', $e->getMessage()), 0, $e);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does ini_get() have to do with sf2 config?